# Differential Equations: Separable Equations

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

How would you solve $y' = {(3x^2-e^x)}/{(2y-7)}$ with a initial condition of $y(0)=2$?

For my attempt, I computed the following with some skipped steps due to being unfamiliar with Latex format.

$$y^2 - 7y = x^3 - e^x + c$$
$$c = -11$$
$$(y-7/2)^2  = x^3 - e^x +5/4$$
$$y=7/2 + sqrt(x^3 - e^x +5/4)$$

But my solution is incorrect. Can someone point out where I am making my mistake at? Also how can you determine the interval in which the solution is defined?

Comment: first question where did you get $c=-11$?

Answer (score 2):

First, find $y$ and then solve for $c$.

You were okay, but should have written:

$$(y-7/2)^2  = x^3 - e^x + c + 49/4 = x^3 - e^x + c $$

since we can combine constants into another arbitrary constant, and this gives:

$$y(x) = ~ \dfrac{1}{2}\left(\pm \sqrt{4x^3-4e^x+c}+7\right)$$

Now, for the negative solution, we solve for $c$, which yields $c = 13$.

The positive solution does not have a solution for the IC, so we drop it.

The final solution is:

$$y(x) = ~ \dfrac{1}{2}\left(-\sqrt{4x^3-4e^x+13}+7\right)$$

Comment: I am able to read deleted posts, and your comment "OP does not want to try a different approach, so removed." is untrue and misleading. I have tried your alternative substitution and it does not even allow one to find the complementary solution, never mind explain the particular solution which was the actual question.

Answer (score 1):

First $c=-9$ and then complete it